# unable connect python with sql server 2008 remotely

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I try to connect python by the library pyodbc with sql server remotely using ubuntu but I failed.

This is my code:

```
server = "INA01SRV03A\ANA01SQL020"
database = "General_Ops_Pricing"
username = "usernameMy"
password = "passwordMy"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password + "'")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error as follows: pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: What driver are you using on Ubuntu? FreeTDS or the MS ODBC driver?